# Android Virtual Device wont show on the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the the latest android studio 2.0 and the recent sdk for Android 6.0. Just recently, this problem started where my AVD wont show up on the emulator. Details are: I create a new AVD n try to run it, the loading emulator window shows up n keeps running in the background forever and in the Android studio shows msgs that the emulator is setting up n then running (no error msgs) but the emulator doesn't show up on the screen. And when i try to run my project, there are no devices shown online. I have tried everything like reinstalling the Android Studio n sdk. I tried searching online but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Android emulator is slow and buggy. Try [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com)

Comment: Emulator is not slow, it doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above problem myself, since there was no complete 
answer available anywhere on the internet. 
The avd didn't show up because the disc images of avd (cache.img, userdata.img, etc ) in the sdk were corrupted. There could be a no. of reasons for this including antivirus quarantine, or windows 8.0 issue, or it got corrupted due to unexpected crashing of emulator.

But the following steps solved my issue.

1) Uninstalling all antivirus and antimalware.

2) Running services for system scan

3) Uninstalling and deleting all android studio and android sdk files including the .android, .gradle and other folders.

4) Downloading and installing the adt bundle (studio and sdk) from android developer site.

And the fresh installation could bring up the emulator online without any issues.